# Why is quartz scheduler suddenly stops triggering jobs after some days without any error?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I have written the below code to schedule the jobs using quartz scheduler , these jobs happens to be triggered properly for some days(3 or 4 days) and suddenly stops triggering next day completely. Please suggest me anything that is wrong in my code.

```
    import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
    import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;

    import java.time.ZoneId;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.TimeZone;

    import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
    import org.quartz.Job;
    import org.quartz.JobDetail;
    import org.quartz.JobKey;
    import org.quartz.Scheduler;
    import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
    import org.quartz.Trigger;
    import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
    import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


    @Service
    public class JobSchedulerServiceImpl implements JobSchedulerService {

        private static LoggerUtil logger = new LoggerUtil(JobSchedulerServiceImpl.class);


        @Autowired
        StdSchedulerFactory facSchedulerFactory;

        @Override
        public boolean createJob(TaskSchedulerInfo taskSchedulerInfo) throws SchedulerException {

            boolean flag = false;

            switch(taskSchedulerInfo.getTaskId()){

            case "DATA_EXPORT" :
                return scheduleJob(new ShopperDataJobs().getClass(), taskSchedulerInfo);

            case "NEW_DWELL_UPDATE"    :
                return scheduleJob(new OptimizedDataToJob().getClass(), taskSchedulerInfo);

            case "DASHBOARD"    :
                return scheduleJobTimezone(new DashboardCacheJob().getClass(), taskSchedulerInfo);

            case "RESPONSE_TIME"    :
                return scheduleJob(new ResponseTimeReportJob().getClass(), taskSchedulerInfo);

            case "CONVERSION_RATE"    :
                return scheduleJob(new ConversionRateReportJob().getClass(), taskSchedulerInfo);

            case "STORE_TRAFFIC"    :
                return scheduleJob(new StoreTrafficReportJob().getClass(), taskSchedulerInfo);

            case "DWELL_TIME"    :
                return scheduleJob(new DwellTimeReportJob().getClass(), taskSchedulerInfo);

            case "STORE_SUMMARY_VIEW"    :
                return scheduleJob(new StoreSummaryDataExportJob().getClass(), taskSchedulerInfo);

            case "DASHBOARD_CACHE"    :
                return scheduleJob(new DashboardCacheJob().getClass(), taskSchedulerInfo);

            case "LOCATION_SUMMARY_VIEW" :
                return scheduleJob(new LocationSummaryJob().getClass(), taskSchedulerInfo);

            case "DATA_EXPORT_SHIFT_TIMING" :
                return scheduleJob(new ShopperShiftTimingDataJob().getClass(), taskSchedulerInfo);

            }
            return flag;
        }

        public boolean scheduleJob(Class<? extends Job> obj, TaskSchedulerInfo taskSchedulerInfo) throws SchedulerException{
            boolean flag = false;
            Scheduler scheduler = facSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();
            logger.info("Scheduling Job for "+taskSchedulerInfo.getTaskId());
            logger.info("Cron Expression " +taskSchedulerInfo.getCronExpression());
            if(!checkForExistingJobForTask(taskSchedulerInfo)){
                JobDetail job = getJobDetail(obj, taskSchedulerInfo);
                Trigger trigger = getTrigger(job, taskSchedulerInfo.getCronExpression(), taskSchedulerInfo);
                scheduler.start();
                if(trigger != null){
                    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            logger.info("Flag for task is "+flag);
            return flag;    
        }


        public boolean scheduleJobTimezone(Class<? extends Job> obj, TaskSchedulerInfo taskSchedulerInfo) throws SchedulerException{
            boolean flag = false;
            Scheduler scheduler = facSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();

            if(!checkForExistingJobForTask(taskSchedulerInfo)){
                JobDetail job = getJobDetailTimeZone(obj, taskSchedulerInfo);
                Trigger trigger = getTrigger(job, taskSchedulerInfo.getCronExpression(), taskSchedulerInfo);
                scheduler.start();
                if(trigger != null){
                    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            return flag;    
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        @Override
        public boolean updateJob(TaskSchedulerInfo taskSchedulerInfo) throws SchedulerException {
            boolean flag = false;
            Scheduler scheduler = facSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();
            List<? extends Trigger> triggers = scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(JobKey.jobKey(taskSchedulerInfo.getScheduleId()));
            if(triggers != null && triggers.size()>0){
                Trigger t=  triggers.get(0);
                TriggerBuilder tb = t.getTriggerBuilder();

                Trigger newTrigger = null;
                if(taskSchedulerInfo.getTimezone()!=null && !taskSchedulerInfo.getTimezone().isEmpty()){
                    if ((Constants.TaskFrequency.Daily.name()).equalsIgnoreCase(taskSchedulerInfo.getFrequency())) {
                        newTrigger = tb.startAt(Date.from(taskSchedulerInfo.getStartDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of(taskSchedulerInfo.getTimezone())).toInstant()))
                                .withIdentity(taskSchedulerInfo.getScheduleId())
                                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(taskSchedulerInfo.getCronExpression()).inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(taskSchedulerInfo.getTimezone()))).build();
                    } else {
                        newTrigger =  tb.withIdentity(taskSchedulerInfo.getScheduleId())
                                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(taskSchedulerInfo.getCronExpression()).inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(taskSchedulerInfo.getTimezone()))).build();
                    }
                }
                if(newTrigger!=null){
                    logger.info("Updated Job for "+taskSchedulerInfo.getTaskId());
                    logger.info("Cron Expression " +taskSchedulerInfo.getCronExpression());
                    scheduler.rescheduleJob(t.getKey(), newTrigger);
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            return flag;
        }

        public JobDetail getJobDetail(Class<? extends Job> obj, TaskSchedulerInfo taskSchedulerInfo) {

            return newJob(obj).withIdentity(JobKey.jobKey(taskSchedulerInfo.getScheduleId()))
                    .usingJobData("tenantId", taskSchedulerInfo.getTenantId())
                    .usingJobData("storeId", taskSchedulerInfo.getBaseStore().getStoreId())
                    .usingJobData("timeZone", taskSchedulerInfo.getTimezone()).build();
        }

        public JobDetail getJobDetailTimeZone(Class<? extends Job> obj, TaskSchedulerInfo taskSchedulerInfo) {

            return newJob(obj).withIdentity(JobKey.jobKey(taskSchedulerInfo.getScheduleId()))
                    .usingJobData("tenantId", taskSchedulerInfo.getTenantId())
                    .usingJobData("storeId", taskSchedulerInfo.getBaseStore().getStoreId())
                    .usingJobData("timezone", taskSchedulerInfo.getTimezone())
                    .build();
        }

        public Trigger getTrigger(JobDetail job, String cron, TaskSchedulerInfo taskSchedulerInfo) {
            Trigger trigger = null;

            if(taskSchedulerInfo.getTimezone()!=null && !taskSchedulerInfo.getTimezone().isEmpty()){
                if ((Constants.TaskFrequency.Daily.name()).equalsIgnoreCase(taskSchedulerInfo.getFrequency())) {
                    trigger = newTrigger().forJob(job)
                            .startAt(Date.from(taskSchedulerInfo.getStartDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of(taskSchedulerInfo.getTimezone())).toInstant()))
                            .withIdentity(taskSchedulerInfo.getScheduleId())
                            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cron).inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(taskSchedulerInfo.getTimezone())).withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
                            .build();
                } else {
                    trigger = newTrigger().forJob(job).withIdentity(taskSchedulerInfo.getScheduleId())
                            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cron).inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(taskSchedulerInfo.getTimezone())).withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()).build();
                }
            }

            return trigger;
        }

        public boolean checkForExistingJobForTask(TaskSchedulerInfo taskSchedulerInfo) throws SchedulerException{
            Scheduler scheduler = facSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();
            List<? extends Trigger> triggers = scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(JobKey.jobKey(taskSchedulerInfo.getScheduleId()));
            boolean flag = false;
            if(triggers != null && triggers.size()>0){
                flag = true;
            }
            return flag;
        }
    <!--deleting jobs -->
        @Override
        public boolean deleteJobs(List<TaskSchedulerInfo> taskSchedulerInfos)
     throws SchedulerException {
<!-- getting scheduler factory bean object-->
            Scheduler scheduler = facSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();
            boolean status =false;
            List<JobKey> jobkeys = new ArrayList<JobKey>();
            for(TaskSchedulerInfo taskSchedulerInfo : taskSchedulerInfos){
                if(checkForExistingJobForTask(taskSchedulerInfo)){
                    jobkeys.add(JobKey.jobKey(taskSchedulerInfo.getScheduleId()));
                }
            }
            if(jobkeys != null && jobkeys.size()>0){
                scheduler.deleteJobs(jobkeys);
                status=true;
            }
            return status;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this? Running into the same issue.